# Как в PHP научить cURL поддерживать http/2?

Tags: php, ios, api, curl, http2

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь работать с api для push-уведомлений ios и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Использую примерно вот такой код:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.development.push.apple.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $page;
```

Возвращается следующая ошибка:
HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 504f5354202f20485454502f312e310d0a486f73743a2061

Судя по всему, cURL не умеет использовать протокол http/2.
В конфиге apache подключал модуль http2, не помогло.
Использую PHP7.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно научить cURL в PHP использовать http/2.
Работаю на локальном сервере под Windows 10. Использую сборку OpenServer.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: *cURL не умеет использовать протокол http/2* -- поправочка: **ваша версия** curl.

Comment: Тут вроде есть ответ http://stackoverflow.com/a/34609756/6120970

Comment: @D-side Версия cURL: 7.49.1